# macOS print / iterate all files from specific mount volume

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, filesystems, mount

My objective is to iterate all files belongs to a specific filesystem and apply a callback function on each of them.

Currently, I'm doing so with a recursive C function that prints all the files from a specific folder and called recursively on sub-folders.

Unfortunately, I never manage to reach the total number of files contains by this mount as given by `getmntinfo`, perhaps it's because some are not ready data regular files (meaning soft-links,pipes, sockets, etc..)

Is there any a high level objective-C framework for iterating all the data files from a specific mount point?

My ideal approach would be to iterate the files in ascending inode id, and not according to their location on the folder hierarchy.

I've found out that I can create file enumerator using `enumeratorAtURL` but what If this URL/Path contain sub-folders that are mounted to remote filesystem .. I only interested in the containing mount files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the C-level `fts(3)` functions ([Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fts.3.html)). These can be limited to a single device and provide the information needed to determine special files. Using them from Objective-C is straightforward.

HTH

Comment: Do you know if there's an option to know the total number of files to traverse in advance (prior to the traversing itself) ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 - To my knowledge there is not single call which returns this for a directory tree, but you can get this information for a whole volume, see `getattrlist(2)` for the information you can get beyond what the `stat(2)` performed by `fts(3)` provides.